# How to disable context from URL in Views

Tags: views

I use D7.
I have a view which I want to show only current user. Those fields, in the view, are related to the current user via relationship of Profile. So, I can also say that the current user can view their own profile's fields.

So, I set 'User: Uid' as 'User ID from logged in user' on contextual filer. But, if I write non-current user's uid after page's path(Let's say '/test-user') like '/test-user/100', it outputs that user's(uid=100) fields.Even if I set 'global $user; return $user->uid;' with PHP Code for User: Uid instead, I got the same result.

For some reason,  with Field Permission module, I set those fields as 'View anyone's value for field_name'. So, I have to control the visibility in this view somehow.

Can anybody give me some advice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Actually this doesn't disable a context from URL. But it worked for my demand.

Click 'add' under Filter criteria.
->Select 'User: Current'.
->Select 'Is the logged in user' as 'Yes'.

That's all.